# contar quantos dias um intervalo de data tem em outro intervalo de data

Tags: mysql, sql

Bom dia, estou fazendo uma query (mysql) e tenho quatro datas `periodo1inicio`, `periodo1final`, `periodo2inicio` e `periodo2final`. Eu preciso contar quantos dias do período 2 está contido no período 1.

Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda com isso, por favor?

Agradeço desde já, abraço.

### EDIT

imagine que eu tenha um barracao pra guardar barcos e eu tive um barco guardado la de 01/01/2014 até 31/01/2014 e durante esse período o valor da diária mudou duas vezes, do dia 02/12/2013 até 15/01/2014 a diária custava X e de 16/01/2014 até 15/02/2014 a diária custava Y.

eu preciso saber que 15 dias eu cobro a diária X e o restante dos dias eu cobro a taxa Y.

Não sei se o exemplo ajuda ou atrapalha.

Comment: Você quer dizer a diferença entre data 2 e data 1? Você pode usar a função do mySQL DATEDIFF. Você pode saber mais em: http://www.rafaeltheodoro.com.br/mysql/como-calcular-diferenca-de-entre-datas-timestamp-date-ou-time-no-mysql/

Comment: O `periodo2inicio` é sempre maior que  o `periodo1inicio`?

Comment: Nem sempre @Lucas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A princípio, você tem três casos a considerar:

1. O começo do `periodo2`, o qual vou chamar de `p2`, é antes ou igual ao começo do `periodo1`, chamado a partir de agora como `p1`. Nesse caso, a resposta fica sendo o número de dias entre o começo de `p1` e o fim de `p1` ou `p2`, o que for menor.
2. O fim do `p2` é depois ou igual ao fim do `p1`, nesse caso a resposta é o começo de `p1` ou `p2`, o que for maior, subtraido do fim de `p1`.
3. Ambos os extremos são diferentes, então deve-se decidir qual começo é maior e qual fim é menor. A diferença desses começo maior e fim menor é o número de dias em comum.

Então, em pseudocódigo, seria algo como:

```
d1.inicio = periodo1inicio
d1.fim = periodo1fim
d2.inicio = periodo2inicio
d2.fim = periodo2fim
//Caso 1
se d2.inicio = d1.inicio
  entao se d1.fim <= d2.fim
          entao return DATEDIFF(d1.inicio, d1.fim)
          senao return DATEDIFF(d1.inicio, d2.fim)
  fim-se
fim-se
//Caso 2
se d2.fim = d1.fim
  entao se d1.inicio <= d2.inicio
          entao return DATEDIFF(d2.inicio, d1.fim)
          senao return DATEDIFF(d1.inicio, d1.fim)
  fim-se
fim-se
//Caso 3
se d2.inicio < d1.inicio
  entao se d2.fim < d1.fim
          entao return DATEDIFF(d1.inicio, d2.fim)
          senao return DATEDIFF(d1.inicio, d1.fim)
        fim-se
  senao se d2.fim < d1.fim
          entao return DATEDIFF(d2.inicio, d2.fim)
          senao return DATEDIFF(d2.inicio, d1.fim)
        fim-se
  fim-se
fim-se
```

Espero que não tenha ficado confuso.

Comment: muito obrigado @mutlei creio que é isso mesmo. vou passar pra query. Obrigado

Comment: Pra query isso não funciona. Teria de ser uma stored procedure.

Comment: exato, só me confundi rss. obrigado novamente

Answer (score 3):

Você pode contar a diferença de dias entre duas datas no MySQL usando a função `DATEDIFF`.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), '2015-01-01'); //Retorna 56 (Base: 26/02/2015);
```

Para o seu caso: `SELECT DATEDIFF(periodo2inicio, periodo1inicio) FROM ....;`

Caso não obtenha o resultado esperado, por favor avise. (Dependendo das datas e a ordem especificada no DATEDIFF o resultado pode ser negativo);

Existem também outras funções como `TIMEDIFF`, `TIMESTAMPDIFF`

**Referências:**

[Como Calcular diferença de entre DATAS (TIMESTAMP, DATE ou TIME) no Mysql](http://www.rafaeltheodoro.com.br/mysql/como-calcular-diferenca-de-entre-datas-timestamp-date-ou-time-no-mysql/)

[Documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)